# How do I monitor a newly created outgoing email (pressing 'New Email' or the like) message for changes in MS Outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook

**In brief**: I wish to press 'New Email' and then monitor the resulting email for events, specifically the addition of an attachment.

I'm working in VBA under MS Outlook. I am looking to monitor a newly drafted email for any added attachments. My goal is to use the AttachmentAdd event to trigger updates on the email when the attachment is added.
What I think I need to do is to know when the 'New Email' is created that I can start to listen for the event. I do this with other folders by initializing them 'WithEvents'. Thereby, I imagine that I'd wish to do the same with the folder/collection where 'New Email' is spawned. How might I set up such a Listen? Where does a 'New Email' get created in the hierarchy of collections within Outlook? I'm missing where to place my initial hook.

Here is an example of what I do for a folder I know:

```
Private WithEvents olDeletedItems As Items

'Initialize system to establish locations to monitor
Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim objNS As NameSpace
  Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
  Set objNS = Application.Session

  'Instantiate objects declared WithEvents
  Set objFolder = objNS.Folders("me@email.com").Folders("Deleted Items")
  Set olDeletedItems = objFolder.Items
End Sub

'Actions on Deleted Items
'Marked deleted items as read as they are deleted
Private Sub olDeletedItems_ItemAdd(ByVal x As Object)
  x.UnRead = False
  x.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Using the 'Immediate Window' I've found that the new Mail Item has the parent of 'Outbox', but that the outbox does not trigger an itemAdd event until the moment of sending.

Comment: The Drafts folder is likely the one to monitor.

Comment: Drafts is only added to if you save the draft. As long as it is still just a work in progress, it doesn't register to a collection. Digging around it looks like I'll need to monitor the 'Inspectors'.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the result can be obtained by motoring the 'Inspectors'. Find when a new 'Inspector' is created and then use that to pull the current 'MailItem'. This 'MailItem' can then be monitored for events.

```
'Monitor for Inspector Events
Private WithEvents olInspectors As Inspectors
'Delcare a place to work with a MailItem that is monitored
Private WithEvents olTempMail As MailItem 

'I use this to instantiate all my monitors
Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Set olInspectors = Application.Inspectors 'Initialize
End Sub

'Here we look for a new Inspector to be created,
'then pull the item from the inpsector and push it
'to the olTempMail var that we can watch it for events
Private Sub olInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal x As Inspector)
  Set olTempMail = x.CurrentItem
End Sub

'Here is a sample event watch where we respond to an
'attachment being added to the MailItem pulled from 
'the inspector above.
Private Sub olTempMail_attachmentadd(ByVal x As Attachment)
  Debug.Print x.DisplayName
End Sub
```

In application, this will need to have some filtration and conditionals added to make it work well. But this should get things moving towards being able to react to events that are created for a new MailItem created when the 'New Email' button is pressed in MS Outlook.